# find: missing argument to `-exec'

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting

when I'm trying to use this command

```
var1=`sudo -u psoadmin -H -s ssh daill_scp@files.dc1.responsys.net find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +14 -exec ls -lh  \{} \; | awk '{print $5, $9}'|egrep -v '^./upload|^./download|^./archive|^\.'`
```

it is throwing me as

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Please let me know if i made any mistakes in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got too many shells doing some processing in there. Also, using backticks is a bad idea especially when there's going to be backslashes in them. You should use the `$(...)` syntax instead.

`sudo -s` starts a shell to run the command, but with `sudo` trying to escape some of the special characters for the shell. You don't want to use that.

`ssh` runs a shell on the remote host to interpret the command line that is made of the concatenation of the arguments (with space in between).

So in:

```
var1=`sudo -u psoadmin -H -s ssh daill_scp@files.dc1.responsys.net find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +14 -exec ls -lh  \{} \;`
```

`sudo` runs:

```
"/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", 
  "ssh daill_scp\\@files.dc1.responsys.net find \\.  -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime \\+14 -exec ls -lh \\{\\} \\;"]
```

(`/bin/bash` or whatever the login shell of the user is).

Notice how `sudo` escaped `.`, `+`, `}`, but not backslash for no particularly good reason.

Then that bash will run:

```
"/usr/bin/ssh", ["ssh", "daill_scp@files.dc1.responsys.net", "find", ".", "-maxdepth", "1", "-type", "f", "-mtime", "+14", "-exec", "ls", "-lh", "{}", ";"]
```

`ssh` will concatenate those and run on remote host:

```
"$SHELL", ["$SHELL", "-c", "find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime + 14 -exec ls -lh {} ;"]
```

(where `$SHELL` is the login shell of the remote user this time).

That `;` above is not escaped, so interpreted as a command separator and not passed to `find` which is why `find` complains that that `-exec` is not terminated.

Here, you want:

```
var1=$(
  sudo -u psoadmin -H ssh daill_scp@files.dc1.responsys.net '
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +14 -exec ls -lh {} \;' |
    awk '{print $5, $9}' |
    egrep -v '^./upload|^./download|^./archive|^\.'
)
```

(not that that command (especially the `egrep` part) makes a lot of sense).

Comment: Awesome!! Really great! It worked!Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try on this way:

```
...-exec ls -lh {} \;...
```

(remove backslash before curly bracket)
Double quotes:

```
var1=`sudo -u psoadmin -H -s ssh daill_scp@files.dc1.responsys.net "find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +14 -exec ls -lh  {} \; "| awk '{print $5, $9}'|egrep -v '^./upload|^./download|^./archive|^\.'`
```

Comment: I tried that also but it did not work...It is throwing same error "find: missing argument to `-exec'"

Comment: Have you put the entire find in double quotes as it need to be executed on remote site?

Comment: I tried now, It did not work:( its throwing me syntax error!

Comment: I edit my answer with example, try it on this way

Comment: And as you can do sudo what is the reason do not get the key from psoadmin user and use it w/o sudo?

Comment: Yeah,I tried it now! Again it is throwing same error

Answer (score 0):

> when I'm trying to use this command
>
> ```
> var1=`sudo -u psoadmin -H -s ssh daill_scp@files.dc1.responsys.net find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +14 -exec ls -lh  \{} \; | awk '{print $5, $9}'|egrep -v '^./upload|^./download|^./archive|^\.'`
> ```
>
> it is throwing me as
>
> ```
> find: missing argument to `-exec'
> ```

You should use this:

```
var1=`sudo -u psoadmin -H -s ssh daill_scp@files.dc1.responsys.net "find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +14 -exec ls -lh  {} \;  | tr -s [:space:] | cut -d ' ' -f 5,9 | egrep -v '^./upload|^./download|^./archive|^\.'"`
```

1. Use `"find [..]"`
2. Use `tr`

   ```
   -s, --squeeze-repeats
         replace each input sequence of a repeated character that is listed in SET1 with a single occurrence of that character
   ```
3. Use `cut`

   ```
   -d, --delimiter=DELIM
         use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter
   -f, --fields=LIST
         select only these fields;  also print any line that contains no delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified
   ```

Comment: I tried this also,Again im getting same error message"find: missing argument to `-exec'";(

Comment: Which shell is running on the server?

Comment: I just tried in another way as var1=`sudo -u psoadmin -H -s ssh daill_scp@files.dc1.responsys.net find /home/cli/daill_scp -maxdepth 1 -mtime +14  -printf '%k %p\n' |egrep -v '^upload|^download|^archive|^\.'`

Comment: But this also did not work

Comment: find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
 it throws error like above mentioned

Comment: It is difficult to answer two questions in one, if a question makes the other redundant.

Comment: Use `"find ... "` with double-quote. I've already written.